# Mobile Safari Web App - clicks and gestures are rather unresponsive

Tags: ios, ipad, html, user-interface, mobile-safari

I have developed an HTML5 web app specifically for iPad devices (mobile Safari).  It seems to me that the HTML buttons and click-events within the app are somewhat unresponsive compared to buttons and gestures on native iOS apps.  Has anyone else noticed this phenomenon? Does anyone have any words of wisdom on why this is happening, and how such buttons could be made more responsive?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Enabling CSS active pseudo styles in Mobile Safari](http://miniapps.co.uk/blog/post/enable-css-active-pseudo-styles-in-mobile-safari/) makes clickable elements more responsive.
And Google has a document: ["Creating Fast Buttons for Mobile Web Applications"](http://code.google.com/mobile/articles/fast_buttons.html)
It says "Touchend events are fired with no delay so this is significantly faster than click events, however there are a few problems to consider:" But i didn't realize any speed difference between click or tap events on IOS.

Also the performance depends on the device, IOS versions and prensentation type of your web app (in safari, as a home-screen web-app, or in UIWebView) and this affect responsiveness too. See performance charts at http://thetechjournal.com/electronics/iphone/report-ios-5-browser-performance-test.xhtml

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, with an accepted answer already, but I was working on a similar problem, and I found the answer to my issue.  Hopefully this helps some other people who might land here from a Google search, and find that the accepted answer doesn't really provide all the info you need.

I found the solution to my problem here...

http://developer.telerik.com/featured/300-ms-click-delay-ios-8

If that link ever goes bad, the gist of it is that mobile browsers purposefully delay click events from firing for 300ms, so they can tell if the gesture was really a double tap to zoom vs a regular tap to click.

There are different built-in solutions to the issue for Chrome / Firefox / IE, but for Safari there really is no build-in solution; instead you can use a "fast click" javascript library that avoids the 300ms delay by listening to touchend events instead of the click event.  I do realize the accepted answer mentions touchend events briefly, but it didn't really give the background explanation as to why that would be needed.

So there you have it - if you face a similar issue, try searching for a "fast click" library, or follow the suggestions at that blog that I linked to.  Hope this helps.